# ibm wcs removing "No inventory"

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs

A developer is asked to remove the "No inventory" options that appears in the store publish wizard when publishing ExtendedsitesV2.sar. Which file should be modified in ExtendedSitesV2.sar before Publishing?

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to edit is Store-refs.xml